# Displaying tables after a page reload in LARAVEL

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

The problem is, after page reload, the table is gone. how can I make it stay even after page reload

So, the first step is, the user is asked how many rows the column should have

[image: this is the first step]

then after clicking create, the table will be created, so for example, if the user typed and submitted 5, it will be like this

[image: step2]

after clicking the Save grading computation, the table won't be editable and the button will disappear. **How can I display the table even after the page reload? Ill provide the codes below**

[image: step 3]

this is the table where i store the value

[image: step4]

**jQuery Code**

```
$("#btn-create").click(function(){
    $(".hide-on-create").hide();
        var numRows = $("#criteria").val();

        var table = $("<table>").addClass("tablesaw table-bordered no-wrap").attr('data-tablesaw-mode','swipe')
        .css({'width': '40%', 'border': '2px solid black', 'align': 'center', 'margin': '0 auto'});
        var img1 = "../assets/images/percentage.jpg";
        var img2 = "../assets/images/description.jpg";
        var img3 = "../assets/images/points.jpg";
        var thead = $("<thead>").css({'border': '2px solid black'});
        var tbody = $("<tbody>").css({'border': '2px solid black'});
        var headRow = $("<tr>").css({'border': '2px solid black'});
        headRow.append("<th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align:center; background-color:#1e88e5; color:white;'>Percentage</th><th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align:center; background-color:#1e88e5; color:white;'>Description/Letter Grade/Numeric</th><th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align:center; background-color:#1e88e5; color:white;'>   Point Equivalence per unit</th>");
        thead.append(headRow);
        table.append(thead);
        for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            var row = $("<tr>").css({'border': '2px solid black'});
            row.append("<td style='border: 2px solid black; ' contenteditable='true'></td><td style='border: 2px solid black; ' contenteditable='true'></td><td style='border: 2px solid black; ' contenteditable='true'></td>");
            
            tbody.append(row);
        }
        
        table.append(tbody);
        $("#table-container").append(table);
        $("#table-container").append("<div style='display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; padding: 10px; width': '40%'><a class='img-link' href='"+img1+"' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#percentage-modal' title=' Guide to Percentage' style='margin-right: 150px'>What is this?</a> <a class='img-link' href='"+img2+"'data-toggle='modal' data-target='#description-modal' title='Guide to Numeric/Letter Grade' style='margin-right: 250px'>What is this?</a> <a class='img-link' href='"+img3+"' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#point-modal' title=' Guide to Points' style='margin-right: 30px'>What is this?</a></div>");
        
        $("#create-btn").show();
        $("td").on("blur", function() {
            var newVal = $(this).html();
            // do something with the new value, such as saving it to a database
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/step11-register',
                data: {
                    newVal: newVal,
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log("Data stored Successfully!");
                }
            });
        });
});

$("#create-btn").click(function(){
var rows = $("#table-container tbody tr").map(function() {
    var cells = $(this).find("td");
    return {
        percentage: $(cells[0]).text(),
        description: $(cells[1]).text(),
        num_point: $(cells[2]).text()
    };
}).get();
    console.log(rows)
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/step11-register',
        data: {
            rows: rows,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Data stored Successfully!");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/step11/{id}' ,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var cells = $("#table-container tbody tr td");
                        $(cells[i*3]).text(data[i].percentage);
                        $(cells[i*3+1]).text(data[i].description);
                        $(cells[i*3+2]).text(data[i].num_point);
                    }
                }
            });

                $("#create-btn").hide();
                $(".img-link").hide();
                $("#table-container td").prop("contenteditable", false);
                $("#table-container td").addClass("readonly-table-cell");
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller.php code**

```
public function step11($id)
{
    
    // Retrieve user and applicant information from the database
    $data['user'] = ApplicantInfoModel::where('app_id','=', Session::get('loginId'))->first();
    $data['user1'] = ComApplicationModel::where('id', '=' ,Session::get('loginId'))->first();
    $data['user2'] = ComPrerequisitesModel::where('reg_id', '=' ,Session::get('loginId'))->get();
 
    

    // Render the view with the data and lists
    return view("enrollment-steps.step11", $data, [

        'data' => $data['user1'],
        'data' => $data['user'],
        'data' => $data['user2'],
    ]); 
   
}
```

Comment: Do you have your table and the values saved in the database?

Comment: I have the data stored in the database, look for the updated question for reference

Comment: So just check if the table exists and make it with `php` on page generation. Or I am missing something here?

Comment: I would make a `php` function to make a table either empty or with values and use it instead of `javascript` so you won't have to duplicate the same thing in both sides. You can call this function on page load if there are some table in the database, or get it via ajax if you need to get a new empty table

Comment: thanks for that good insight! I will consider your suggestion. I'm looking and searching for ways and opinions on how to populate a table since it is my first time doing this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code shows only the onClick actions, that do not load the data from the db.

First you need a new controller method to read the saved data. This method would get called on every GET request to the page.

```
public function read(){
  // get the data from db and assign it to the view or make it available for a json request
}
```

If you are keen to do that over jQuery, you should have a code that does something like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   // e.g get the saved data either by ajax to the new controller method 
});
```

Or you could show it directly in the view like this:

```
@if( $data ) 
 <table> ...data </table>
@endif>
```

Comment: how can i do the last option? it looks like its easier to use. is there a documentation i can read about it?

Comment: i have a div instead of a table 

 <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; padding: 10px">
 <button class="btn btn-md waves-effect waves-light btn-info" id="create-btn" type="submit"  >Save Grading Computation</button>
   </div>
   <div id="table-container"></div>

Comment: `public function read(){
   $data = // get data from the db
   return view ( 'enrollment-steps.step11', compact( 'data' ) );
}`

In the view you need to the replicate html code of the table, when the $data var is present:


`@if( isset( $data ) )
<table> // replicate the table 
  @foreach( $data as $row )
    <tr> 
        <td>{{ $row->id }} </td>
           ........
</table>
@endforeach
@endif`

Comment: souljack like this one like this one <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Percentage</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Num Point</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        foreach($data as $row)
            @if($row->percentage && $row->description && $row->num_point)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $row->percentage }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $row->description }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $row->num_point }}</td>
                </tr>
            endif
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>